# Static vector initialization in cpp file

Tags: c++, vector

I have a problem where I have declared a `static` `string` `vector` in the `.h` file inside a `class` ,

#### `.h` file

```
static std::vector<std::string> VHDSigBuffer;
```

How to use this `vector` in my `class` function Implementations in `cpp` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### In `my_class.h` header

```
class my_class
{  
public:
   // Declaration
   static std::vector<std::string> VHDSigBuffer;
};
```

#### In `my_class.cpp` implementation

```
// Definition
std::vector<std::string> my_class::VHDSigBuffer;
```

Now you can freely use `my_class::VHDSigBuffer`.

Comment: thanks I have done this ,But while pushing values into it have problems , CAn yu help me on that too plzz ?

Comment: @Shafi You need to show the code you are using when 'pushing values' and explain exactly what the problems are. Don't expect people to guess at the problems you are having.

Comment: IN CPP FILE  class::myfunction(){ vectorvariable.push_back(mystring);}    But when I debug the code I found that symbol has not been created so , nothing happens ,but the code compiles

Comment: @Shafi This could be a problem with *static initialisation order*, but I'd need to see more code to be sure. In particular I'd need to know how and when you are calling class::myfunction. I think you should make a new question of this, and *post a lot more code*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate it within your CPP file, with a line like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> MyClass::VHDSigBuffer;
```

This line will be outside any function definition in the CPP file.

Comment: thanks I have done this ,But while pushing values into it have problems , CAn yu help me on that too plzz ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying correctly,

If you want to use this vector in its own class you can access it as `VHDSigBuffer`, or if you want to use it in another class you can access it as `youClass::VHDSigBuffer`.

Comment: @John: How so? `static` attributes of a class cannot be used in a none static method of the same class. Am I wrong?

Comment: I think we can .static members must be initialized globally before using them in our class methods .

Comment: tried it and I was wrong, just changed my answer.